# How to setup Module without Owner in Gnosis setup function using Smart Contract

Tags: gnosis-safe, delegatecall, safe-core

I am trying to setup module by delegate call in setup function of Safe. In my custom factory Smart Contract

```
// Create Gnosis Safe wallet using ProxyFactory
address moduleImplementationAddress = address(moduleImplementation);
address vaultAddress = address(proxyFactory.createProxy(safeImplementation, "0x"));
GnosisSafe vault = GnosisSafe(payable(vaultAddress));
vault.setup(
    _owners,
    _threshold,
    safeImplementation,
    // "0x",
    abi.encodeCall(ModuleManager.enableModule, moduleImplementationAddress),
    address(0),
    address(0),
    0,
    payable(address(0))
);

require(vault.isModuleEnabled(moduleImplementationAddress), "VaultFactory: module is not enabled");
```

but it fails to execute a delegateCall